# Java crashes when resizing JFrame with drawn bufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, drawing, bufferedimage

I am making an interface which contains a drawn image that is sized as big as possible while maintaining aspect ratio within the JFrame. The code below is used to achieve this behavior:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (image == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Calculate what image size fits within the component's bounds
    Dimension fittingImageSize = getFittingImageSize();

    // Scale the image. We use AffineTransform as it's much faster than scaledInstance(...)
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.scale(fittingImageSize.getWidth() / image.getWidth(), fittingImageSize.getHeight() / image.getHeight());
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage((int)fittingImageSize.getWidth(), (int)fittingImageSize.getHeight(), image.getType());
    scaleOp.filter(image, scaledImage);

    // Calculate the offset        
    Point offset = getImageOffset(fittingImageSize);

    // Draw the image
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawImage(scaledImage, offset.x, offset.y, null);
}
```

However, when I resize the JFrame I get a heap space exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(DataBufferInt.java:75)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createPackedRaster(Raster.java:467)
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1032)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:333)
```

As far as I can see, I am not doing anything strange aside from properly sizing the image. However, it seems that this operation is what is causing the issue. Can anyone provide a bunch of pointers at how I can better approach this?

Comment: That is an *error*. It simply means you cannot allocate a large enough contiguous memory block to store your `BufferedImage`. You can either give your VM more memory (`-Xmx` option), or try using the `Graphics2D.drawImage` method that takes an `AffineTransform` parameter and set `RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION` to `VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR`, to scale directly while drawing. In theory this could be faster/use less memory. But it depends...

Comment: @haraldK Thanks for your comment! That method takes a `RenderableImage` as an argument and unfortinately BufferedImage/Image aren't directly convertible to a RenderableImage (nor is there clear documentation on how that can be acheived).

Comment: I was referring to [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.geom.AffineTransform,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)), which has a plain Image as first parameter.

Comment: @haraldK Ahh, I missed that one. I'll give it a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a small workaround to prevent repainting while the component is being resized. I added a `ComponentListener` to the relevant component, and in the `componentResized` method I did the following:

```
@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
    isResizing = true;
    timer.cancel();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isResizing = false;
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }

    }, redrawAfterResizeDelay);
}
```

Then, in `paintComponent` I guard against the `isResizing` boolean: if it's true then `paintComponent` returns early.

It isn't the nicest of fixes, so I am still hoping for better answers, but in my situation this is an acceptable fix.

**Edit: The above fix may work for others, but it was not the underlying problem.**

The problem was in the way I calculated the `fittingImageSize`. When the width divided by the height of the component would be larger than the height divided by the width of the component, then a wrong `fittingImageSize` was returned causing the app to attempt to create a BufferedImage with a width of several million px. That is what ended up causing the memory exceptions.